# How to use NSUserDefault to send selected TableViewCell text to previous ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a static `UITableView` with two prototype cells in my first `UIViewController`. in the first cell there is a label with "select your country". When user tap that cell, it goes to another `UITableViewController` that includes countries. When user select a country, in the first view label text should update with the selected country name. To do that I have to pass the selected data in second `UIViewController` to first view controller. I hope to use `NSUserDefaults` to do that. this is my second view controller with a tableview.

```
@implementation FlightfromTableViewController
{
    NSArray *detailFlights;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    detailFlights = @[@"colombo1",@"colombo2",@"colombo3",@"colombo14",@"colombo15",@"colombo16",@"colombo17"];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {    
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [detailFlights count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identi" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [detailFlights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    Pass *p = [Pass new];
    p.selectedString = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;

      NSString *selecteOne = p.selectedString;
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selecteOne forKey:@"selectedplace"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


}
```

I appreciate if you provide answer with understandable code, because I'm new to iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you don't need to much code in your didSelect method to get your selected string. Just use your array:

```
NSString *selectedText = [detailFlights objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]; // or detailFlights[indexPath.row]
```

And when you come back to your master (first) `ViewController` you need to update your `TableView`, because data has changed. So, add `viewWillAppear` (if you haven't one) method and refresh your table:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear: animated];
  [self.tableView reloadData]; // put here name of your tableView's property
}
```

And then, in your `cellForRow` method:

```
...
if (indexPath.row == 0) { // in first row you store country
  NSString *text = @"Select country"; // default text
  NSString *selectedCountry = [[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedplace"];
  if (selectedCountry) { // if it exist
    text = selectedCountry;
  }
  cell.textLabel.text = text;
}
```

Comment: nice, it works.but I got a small problem here. in my didselectrowatindexpath method.think I select first row in the second tableview. nothing happen.after I clicked another row.it works. any wrong with that method in my code. I'm testing with this simulator.

`  NSString *selectedText = [detailFlights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:selectedText forKey:@"st"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
`

Comment: @Graham try move your code from didDeselect method to didSelect.

Answer (score 2):

`NSUserDefaults` should not be used for application state. It's for user preferences which should persist when the app closes.

The correct way is to pass your data directly between your viewcontrollers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/78496

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @`chedabob`, `NSUserDefaults` should not be used to maintain application state.

Instead, you can use `Protocols` to back propagate the selection in First View Controller.

In your case, just use

```
[[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedplace"];
```

in `viewWillAppear` of `FirstViewController` to update the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from NSUserDefault by using this code in your First View Controller.

```
NSString *selectedPlace = [[NSUserdefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"selectedplace"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegate pattern to inform the first view controller about selected country. For this you have to write protocol in second view controller.

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate

-(void)secondViewController:(UIViewController *)vc selectedCountry:(NSString *)country;

@end

then in 
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
delegate.secondViewController(self) selectedCountry:@"selectedCountry";
}

After that in first view controller you implement this menthod to update the value.